# Como definir esta variable

Tags: android

Estoy usando el código de esta [SerialPortExample](https://github.com/felHR85/SerialPortExample) y quiero definir una variable (mConfigDataBit) para que pueda modificar después pero no logro hacerlo correctamente.

Los posibles valores que puede tomar esta variable mConfigDataBit es:
DATA_BITS_8, DATA_BITS_7, DATA_BITS_6, DATA_BITS_5

```
public static int mConfigDataBit = DATA_BITS_8;

private final BroadcastReceiver usbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        if (arg1.getAction().equals(ACTION_USB_ATTACHED)) {
            boolean ret = builder.openSerialPorts(context, mConfigBaudRate,
                    UsbSerialInterface.mConfigDataBit,
                    UsbSerialInterface.STOP_BITS_1,
                    UsbSerialInterface.PARITY_NONE,
                    UsbSerialInterface.FLOW_CONTROL_OFF);
            if(!ret)
                Toast.makeText(context, "Couldnt open the device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (arg1.getAction().equals(ACTION_USB_DETACHED)) {

            UsbDevice usbDevice = arg1.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            boolean ret = builder.disconnectDevice(usbDevice);

            if(ret)
                Toast.makeText(context, "Usb device disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(context, "Usb device wasnt a serial port", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_USB_DISCONNECTED);
            arg0.sendBroadcast(intent);

        }
    }
};
```

El error que obtengo es: " No se puede resolver el Simbolo 'mConfigDataBit' "

Alguien me podria decir cual es mi error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad `DATA_BITS_8` es una constante pero se encuentra dentro de la clase `UsbSerialInterface` por lo tanto debes hacer referencia a esta clase para obtener su valor:

```
UsbSerialInterface.DATA_BITS_8
```

por lo tanto sería:

```
public static int mConfigDataBit = UsbSerialInterface.DATA_BITS_8;
```

y solo deberías usar esta variable:

```
  boolean ret = builder.openSerialPorts(context, mConfigBaudRate,
                    mConfigDataBit,
                    UsbSerialInterface.STOP_BITS_1,
                    UsbSerialInterface.PARITY_NONE,
                    UsbSerialInterface.FLOW_CONTROL_OFF);
```

Ya que `UsbSerialInterface.mConfigDataBit` en realidad no se encuentra en la clase `UsbSerialInterface`.

---

Pero en realidad te recomiendo tomar el valor directamente de la clase `UsbSerialInterface`:

```
  boolean ret = builder.openSerialPorts(context, mConfigBaudRate,
                    //mConfigDataBit,
                    UsbSerialInterface.DATA_BITS_8, /* Aquí el cambio */
                    UsbSerialInterface.STOP_BITS_1,
                    UsbSerialInterface.PARITY_NONE,
                    UsbSerialInterface.FLOW_CONTROL_OFF);
```